# unresolved import: xrange

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, pydev, eclipse-luna

I have newly started working with Tensorflow Python 2.7 API. I use Ubunto 16.04 LTS, Eclipse Lunar Service Release 2 (4.4.2) and have PyDev version 5.2.0 installed.
Now when I use the command `from six.moves import xrange` eclipse shows me a tiny warning "unresolved import: xrange".
previously the same type of error was raised when I used other import commands like `from __future__ import absolute_import`, but it was solved but not this `unresolved import: xrange` error after creating a new interpretor.

Answer (score 0):

Add **six** to the forced builtins (and reopen the editor).

If you want more details, see the **Forced Builtins** topic on: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html